# LaTeX error creating Huxtable (! LaTeX Error: File `adjustbox.sty' not found.)

Tags: r, pdf, latex, huxtable

I'm creating a PDF report with Huxtable in R. The LaTeX log file returns this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `adjustbox.sty' not found.
```

Following instructions in Huxtable FAQ, I realized missing LaTeX dependencies. However, updating these dependencies also returned error message:

```
> report_latex_dependencies()
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% These are LaTeX packages. You can install them using your LaTex management software,
% or by running `huxtable::install_latex_dependencies()` from within R.
% Other packages may be required if you use non-standard tabulars (e.g. tabulary).

> check_latex_dependencies()
The following LaTeX packages were not found:
adjustbox
Install them using your latex package manager or via install_latex_dependencies().
Error: invalid version specification ‘unknown data field: 'cat-version'’, ‘tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.’

> install_latex_dependencies()
Trying to install packages: caption, siunitx, ulem, colortbl, multirow, threeparttable, wrapfig, adjustbox, tools
If this fails, try running the following on the command line (you may need admin permissions):
  tlmgr install caption siunitx ulem colortbl multirow threeparttable wrapfig adjustbox tools

tlmgr install caption siunitx ulem colortbl multirow threeparttable wrapfig adjustbox tools

C:\Users\vivam\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
tlmgr update --self
name = modes, rootname = modes, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf modes

The command name is C:\Users\vivam\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexmf
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `mf-nowin -ini   -jobname=mf -progname=mf -translate-file=cp227.tcx mf.ini <nul' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
...rs\vivam\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 1:
perl.exe c:\Users\vivam\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl  --sys --all
tlmgr install caption siunitx ulem colortbl multirow threeparttable wrapfig adjustbox tools

C:\Users\vivam\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
Error: invalid version specification ‘unknown data field: 'cat-version'’, ‘tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.’
>
```

Software version:
R: 4.0.2
tinytex: 0.25
huxtable: 5.0.0